# AJAX get data from sql by php and then display data value onto html element

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

**HTML**

```
<input id="box1" type="submit">

$('#box1').click( function() {
 $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    type:"POST",
});
});
```

**PHP insert.php**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "votingcount");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// attempt update query execution
$sql = "UPDATE vote_result SET vote_count = vote_count + 1 WHERE   photo_no=1";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

When the submit button (#box1) is clicked, the UPDATE statement would increase the vote count in SQL by 1. After running the insert.php, at the same time a overlay would appear to show the CURRENT vote count from the SQL, I would want the overlay box content to display the int vote count with the following sql statement : $sql = "SELECT `vote_count` FROM `vote_result` WHERE `photo_no`=1";

How would I allow the .click function for #box1 be able to run another php where I could retrieve the value and update the #clicked value in the following overlay?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="tyedit.jpg" height="1024" width="724" />
            <div id="imagine">
                <span id="clicked">0</span><br/>
                <span id="word">VOTES</span>
            </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: **1.** In the same insert.php file, after the update - select the required value and instead of "Records aded succ.." echo that value. **2.** add a "success" event to your ajax code that takes the returned value and append it to wherever you want.

Comment: @OfirBaruch $sql = "SELECT vote_count  FROM vote_result WHERE photo_no=1" Do you mean to insert that right after the update? My html is a separate file from the insert.php, how would I be able to append the value?

Comment: Follow @bipin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you run your select query after the insert query in insert.php itself.
After successful update query, just run another query to select the vote count from your table.

```
$sql = "SELECT vote_count FROM vote_result WHERE photo_no=1";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['vote_count'];
}
```

The echoed statements are you ajax response, so use callback function on success to update your overlay.

on your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   type:"POST",
   success:function(response){
       $("#clicked").html(response);
   }
});
```

also if you wish to have multiple echoes on your insert.php file you could get a json response using `json_encode()` to all your echoes.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean I had this error when displaying the response.

Comment: @user2728875 have you tried my answer to solve it ??

Comment: make sure your sql is a select query, insert, update or delete query returns boolean - true upon successful modification in database table, false otherwise .... however on select query it returns a mysqli_result as you are fetching data ... i can only imagine that you probably ran mysqli_fetch_assoc() on an update query ??

Comment: Hey @sujanbasnet, I've managed to solve it. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

first change type **submit** to **button**

```
<input id="box1" type="button" value="click">
```

than click event call ajax

```
<script>
$('#box1').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       success: function(data) {
          $("#myModal").modal('show');
          $('#clicked').text(data);
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Change php code like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE vote_result SET vote_count = vote_count + 1 WHERE   photo_no=1";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

   $sql1 = "SELECT vote_count FROM vote_result  WHERE photo_no=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row["vote_count"];

} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($sql);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the while loop in this case.